# How to add column to Jenkins view that displays most recent SCM revision

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm looking for a plugin or setting or something that will add the column that displays the last build's revision number from the SVNPlugin that manages to display that information in the build results page. I'm looking for things that translate Jenkins build # into SVN revision # so I can easily cross reference the two without drilling into a specific build#'s page.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all the answers you are looking for.
http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=258

You will need the following plugins installed [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin)

The groovy code:

```
import hudson.model.* 
import hudson.util.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def workspace = build.getWorkspace()
def ant = new AntBuilder() 
ant.exec(executable: "svn", outputproperty: "output", dir: workspace){ 
    arg(line: "info") 
}

svnInfo = ant.project.getProperty("output")
def pattern = /Last\s+Changed\s+Rev:\s+(\d+)/ 
def matcher = (svnInfo =~ pattern)

def buildLabel = ‘Dev-’ + matcher[0][1]
println ‘setting build label for this build’

build.setDisplayName(buildLabel)
```

If you want a custom build name with the revision number. You will need to install [another plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin).

```
import hudson.model.* 
import hudson.util.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def workspace = build.getWorkspace()
def ant = new AntBuilder() 
ant.exec(executable: "svn", outputproperty: "output", dir: workspace){ 
    arg(line: "info") 
}

svnInfo = ant.project.getProperty("output")
def pattern = /Last\s+Changed\s+Rev:\s+(\d+)/ 
def matcher = (svnInfo =~ pattern)
def build=new ParametersAction([
  new StringParameterValue("revisionSVN", matcher[0][1])
])
```

And then in the jenkins job, set your build name as you want
[image]

EDIT:
*As an alternative you can use SVN_REVISION without using the groovy scripts.
If you have multiple repository links, use SVN_REVISION1, SVN_REVISION2.*

[image: SVN_REVISION]

Comment: I think there may be some robustness issues with the above script for reasons I haven't yet figured out. I'm running about 20 builds across 4 nodes, some of jobs render the SVN tag properly, while others fail to locate directories, and some throw index out of bounds exceptions presumably at the indexing into the regEx matcher. Could be node dependent perhaps. I'mma look into exception handling for Groovy so I can protect the builds against false positive build failures due to script preconditions.

Comment: I'm  not sure what's going on but some jobs this script works, other jobs the rev number never increments but stays stuck on one value. I suspect it might have something to do with the relation of the slave to the master but I'd need to do some diagnostics on all my different jobs and figure out what's going awry. So far this solution's not working consistently out for me.

Comment: Just looked into it, the SVN rev the groovy script is pulling is from a copy of the workspace for that job saved on the master node. That workspace has not been updated for sometime since the job has ran on some slave nodes which are updating. I believe the context of the master is being used due to invoking the groovy via `Execute system Groovy script`. Maybe that's not the right way but I thought I read somewhere that's how you connect to Jenkins.

Comment: Use this ${ENV,var="SVN_REVISION"}